# mediawiki: Assign a unique reference to each article using categories

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

I want to create a unique reference in each article. This is done by using catgories with the following template, which extends the PageID with a thematic prefix.

```
{{Category:{{{1}}}{{PAGEID}}}}
```

I have integrated it into the article like this

```
{{{ReferenceID|Item}}}
```

The text of the template is displayed correctly, but Mediawiki does not recognize it as a category and it is not displayed on the special page "desired categories".

What is the mistake? May there is an other option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of assigning categories to pages is `[[Category:{{{1}}}{{PAGEID}}]]`, not `{{Category:{{{1}}}{{PAGEID}}}}`.

The wikicode `{{{ReferenceID|Item}}}` is meaningful only in a template that has a `ReferenceID` parametre. The template above, which adds category, hasn't.

If `ReferenceID` is the name of the template above, it is inserted like this: `{{ReferenceID|Item}}`, not `{{{ReferenceID|Item}}}`.

The very idea of creating a category for each page is strange. If you want each page to be accessible by a unique ID, create a redirect like `#redirect [[(full page name)]]` under the title `(theme prefix)/(page id)`. You may want to store those redirects in a separate namespace.

Comment: The idea is a similar solution for "what is linking here" but with much less mouse clicks.